# php how to dynamically change variable name?

Tags: php

I have a script that pulls out XML information then puts it into JSON format. I am trying to change the variable name as I put everything into a table for vewing after the json is decoded.

For instance, there are eleven scores that will be listed and rather than write out all eleven I wanted to dynamically change the name as the loops happens. The problem line I am having is in the studentInformation.php file, I put a comment next to it to make it easier to spot. Hopefully I have explained my issue well enough :P

Nodes in xml file (yeah it's only the first tag, but you get the idea)

```
<set1score>
<set2score>
<set3score>
<set4score>
<set5score>
<set6score>
<set7score>
<set8score>
<set9score>
<set10score>
<set11score>
```

xmlParse.php

```
<?php
class xmlParse
{   
    private $xmlFile;

    public function __construct($xmlFile)
    {
        $this->xmlFile = $xmlFile;
    }
    private function xmlVerify($p)
    {
        return pathinfo($p,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='xml';
    }
    public function encodeJSON()
    {
        if($this->xmlVerify($this->xmlFile))
        {
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($this->xmlFile);
       return json_encode($xml->children());
        }
        else
        {
            return ('<script>alert(\'error with xml file validation\');</script>');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

studentInformation.php

```
<?php
class studentInformation extends xmlParse
{
    private $xmlFile;

    public function __construct($xmlFile)
    {
        parent::__construct($xmlFile);
    }
    private function decodeJSON($i)
    {
        $j = json_decode($i);
   return $j;
    }
    public function getStudentInformation()
    {
        $output = '';
   $count = 1;
   foreach($this->decodeJSON($this->encodeJSON($this->xmlFile))->student as $v)
        {
       $output .= "<tr>";
       $output .= "<td>" . $v->lname . "</td>";
       $output .= "<td>" . $v->fname . "</td>";
       $output .= "<td>" . $v->set($count)score . "</td>"; //PROBLEM HERE!!!!!
       $output .= "</tr>";
       $count++;
   }
   return $output;  
}
}
?>
```

Comment: `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` Ugh...

Comment: Why not just `return condition`? In your case, `return pathinfo($p,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'xml'` would suffice.

Comment: Ahh, very nice. I like that much better! Thanks for the heads up ;)

Comment: How does everything else look?

Comment: from your code I understand that: from student 1 you want the tag set1score, from student2, the tag set2score etc. Is that correct?

Comment: @ Remi - That is correct. Marc brought up a good point that it's a horrible design, but that is what I have :)

Answer (score 3):

Horrible horrible design. why not...

```
<score num="1">
<score num="2">
etc...
```

Such a reference would only be necessary if you need to access a specific score anyways. if you're simply using XML as a temporary storage medium for transport, then even a simple `<score>` would do, since you'd just iterate/extract/destroy anyways.

Comment: Thanks Marc, very true after seeing what you have I am an idiot! HAHA! That would make my life much easier :)

Comment: Mike, listen to this advice. The hard part while coding is learning how to make things easy! Harol tried to explain this for ages! ;)

Comment: Man I wish that would sink in! I seem to make things waaaaay too hard for me, but I am learning :)

Comment: @Marc - After working with the XML file the reason I have each scored numbered is for when it get's imported into Micrsoft Excel. It will display the node as a header for easy input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$output .= "<td>" . $v->'set'.$count.'score' . "</td>";`

Comment: I think it's supposed to be double quotes. Sorry Mike

Comment: It's okay Jag, I tried it with double quotes and had no luck. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic variable:

```
$setCount = 'set' .$count. 'score';
$$setCount = $score;
```